# How to dynamically change column renderer of a grid column

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4.2, renderer

I need to apply different renderer for a specific column of a grid.
I have a instance of grid 'myGrid' which has a column 'abc'. How do i set a renderer on column 'abc' dynamically?

Comment: Why change the renderer when you have the option to check your condition inside the renderer itself and renderer the cell accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

The concept of renderer itself is dynamic. You'll have to call the dynamic renderers (which you want to set as renderers) from the main renderer function which is attached statically. Hope it helps!

Here's an example

```
var renderers = {
    'a' : function() {},
    'b' : function() {}
};
Ext.create('MyApp.view.grids.UsersGrid', {
    columns : [{
        text : 'User Date of Birth',
        renderer : function() {
            var rendererIdx;
            return renderers[rendererIdx](arguments);
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: can you give an example?